# Blender only renders one frame instead of the frames I selected

Tags: rendering

I have made a smoke simulation (cache 17 GB) 300 frames (300 sampling with denoising on).

(I turned it down and off for troubleshooting).

I had no problem rendering it, but after I looked into the image stripe it shows that I had 13 (266-278) frames blank, so I tried to re-render those frames, but it is only rendering one frame and saving it {[blender save file](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ihk1zb2kk9ctw38/AAA3LWX1V3EhQ5Fsid7vh_Gea?dl=0)}.

How can fix this problem? I could not render with the sequencer on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you set **Frame step** value:

[image]

Set it back to **1**

This value use to render every N-th frame, with skipping others.

Also, you have a video strip in sequencer (VSE). So blender render from sequencer instead 3d-scene

[image]

Remove this strip, or uncheck sequencer in post progressing tab:

[image]